# UI Design that need to restructure in HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap-3, visual-studio-2022

I want the dropdown design look like as [Mega Menu Dropdown] but the design become like as [Dropdown]. I'm poor in CSS and I need help on this from you.

I am using Bootstrap v3.4.1. Script below will be using to run my server in my form.

```xml
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server">
    <Scripts>
        <%--To learn more about bundling scripts in ScriptManager see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=301884 --%>
        <%--Framework Scripts--%>
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="MsAjaxBundle" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="bootstrap" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebForms.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebForms.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebUIValidation.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebUIValidation.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="MenuStandards.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/MenuStandards.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="GridView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/GridView.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="DetailsView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/DetailsView.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="TreeView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/TreeView.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebParts.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebParts.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="Focus.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/Focus.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebFormsBundle" />
        <%--Site Scripts--%>
    </Scripts>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

My expect design need same like [Mega Menu Dropdown] as shown in the image.

Thank You so much.

[Mega Menu Dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNCBy.png)
[Dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFg5J.png)

Here are my codes:

```css
nav li {
  /* remove all the bullets and baked in style - probably should use div set instead */
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.navbar-link {
  color: #000080;
  background-color: deepskyblue;
}

.navbar-head {
  background-color: #000099;
  font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;
}

.navbar-head2 {
  background-color: deepskyblue;
  font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.navbar-brand>strong {
  color: white;
  font-size: 3.3rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.menu-hr-line {
  /* border-top-width: 3px;*/
  border-top-color: #000099;
}

.dropdown.has-megamenu {
  position: static;
}

.dropdown-header {
  color: #050A30;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  width: 200px;
}

.dropdown-menu .columns-4 {
  min-width: 1300px;
  background-color: #e6ffff;
}

.dropdown-menu .submenu {
  display: block !important;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  /*top: 1px;*/
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-menu > li:hover > .submenu {
  display: block;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-menu li a {
  padding: 5px 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.multi-column-dropdown {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.multi-column-dropdown li a {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  line-height: 1.324624;
  color: #000C66;
  white-space: normal;
}

.multi-column-dropdown li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: cornflowerblue;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle:hover,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle:focus {
  background-color: #777;
  border-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <nav class="navbar-head">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" title="facility portal">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" runat="server" href="~/"><strong>PORTAL</strong></a>
            </div>                
        </div>
    </nav>
    
    <div class="navbar-head2">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

                    <li><a href="~/Home" class="navbar-link">HOME</a></li>

                    <li class="dropdown"><span data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle navbar-link">GENERAL <span class="caret"></span></span>
                        <ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a id="A1" href="#">Chart</a></li>
                            <li><a id="A2" href="#">Document</a></li>
                            <li><a id="A3" href="#">Equipment</a></li>
                            <li><a id="A4" href="#">Utility</a></li>
                            <li><a id="A5" href="#">Plant</a></li>                            
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                    <li class="nav-item dropdown has-megamenu"><span data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle navbar-link">MODULES <span class="caret"></span></span>
                        <ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu multi-column columns-4">
                          <li>
                            <div class="row">

                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                                        <li class="dropdown-header">Report</li>
                                        <li><hr class="border-top-3 solid w-100 menu-hr-line" /></li>
                                        <li class="dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown"><span>Daily</span>
                                            <ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu submenu">
                                                <li><a id="A16" href="#">1</a></li>
                                                <li><a id="A17" href="#">3</a></li>
                                                <li><a id="A18" href="#">5</a></li>
                                                <li><a id="A19" href="#">7</a></li>
                                                <li><a id="A20" href="#">9</a></li>
                                                <li><a id="A21" href="#">12</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                        <li><a id="A7" href="#">Weekly</a></li>
                                        <li><a id="A8" href="#">Abnormality</a></li>
                                        <li><a id="A9" href="#">Plant</a></li>
                                        <li><a id="A10" href="#">Calibration</a></li>
                                        <li><a id="A11" href="#">Supervising</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                                        <li class="dropdown-header">Inventory</li>
                                        <li><hr class="solid w-100 menu-hr-line" /></li>
                                        <li><a id="A12" href="#">Items</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                                        <li class="dropdown-header">Schedule</li>
                                        <li><hr class="solid w-100 menu-hr-line" /></li>
                                        <li><a id="A13" href="#">Master</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                                        <li class="dropdown-header">Documentation</li>
                                        <li><hr class="solid w-100 menu-hr-line" /></li>
                                        <li><a id="A14" href="#">Equipment</a></li>
                                        <li><a id="A15" href="#">Drawing</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                          </li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>

                    <li><a href="#" class="navbar-link">OFFINE MANAGEMENT SYSTEM</a></li>

                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @InSync. Could you help me on this for the css part that I need to restructure? 
I have see you help me to do edited for some part and I see nothing where does you make the changes yet. Thank You.

Comment: That's not the point of [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing). Sorry, but I don't know what the solution is; if I did, I would have posted an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).